# CentOS 6 endless boot from USB drive

Tags: boot, centos

I'm trying to install CentOS 6 from a USB drive. I created the image with Universal USB Installer in Windows, and the ISO was taken from the official mirror.

When the system is loading, the first image (CentOS) appears along with the sign "Automatic boot will be in 10 seconds". After it reaches 0 seconds the process repeats again from 10 to 0.

What could be the problem? I've tried it with minimal-iso and netinstall-iso instead but get the same result.

Comment: Have you tried to press a button during the count down to open the bootloader menu?

Comment: which button exactly?

Comment: Any button should work (but you better try the normal keyspace, no special keys).

Comment: yes, the menu appears, but neither Boot nor textual boot works. I mean when I press Boot or any other option nothing changes, still "automatic boot will be in x seconds" continues.

Comment: nothing happens, only boot from local disk works - and the current os is loaded

Comment: Do you have the possibility to check the CentOS iso from a CD (or int a VM)? Just to make sure there is nothing wrong with your USB device.

Comment: this is really strange on VM the boot process is absolutely normal, but I've changed 2 usb flash drives and still endless boot

Comment: I must admit, I dont know Universal USB Installer, but maybe you should use an alternative.

Comment: I have the same problem. @Sergey did you solved the problem?